# Set a minimal order amount for a specific User role in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, checkout, user-roles

I'm creating a wholesale website. Looking on here I was able to already find code for switching between two user roles after customers place a first order.  Now I just need to be able to set minimum order amounts for different user roles on the cart/checkout page and most of what I've been finding does way more than I need it to. Searching online I was able to find this bit of code:

```
<?php
/*
Author: Doug Edgington
Description: Require a minimum order total in Woocommerce for a user role
*/
function dee_minimum_order_total_required() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        global $woocommerce;
        global $current_user;

        get_currentuserinfo();

        $dee_user_roles = $current_user->roles;
        $dee_user_role = array_shift($dee_user_roles);

        $dee_minimum = 50;
        if ( $woocommerce->cart->subtotal < $dee_minimum  && $dee_user_role == 'wholesale_buyer') {
            $woocommerce->add_error( sprintf( 'Wholesale users must have a minimum order total of $%s to place an order.' , $dee_minimum ) );
        }
    } //end main if statement
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'dee_minimum_order_total_required' );
```

How would I add more than 1 user role to this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are using is really old and obsolete. The code below will check cart items for  Wholesale user role that should have a minimal order amount:

```
// Cart and checkout validation
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'minimal_total_required' ); // Cart and Checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'minimal_total_required' ); // Checkout (optional)
function minimal_total_required() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    ## -- YOUR SETTINGS BELOW -- ##

    $min_amount    = 50; // Minimal order amount
    $targeted_role = 'wholesale_buyer'; // User role

    // Exit for non logged users or when minimal order amout is reached
    if( $user->ID == 0 || WC()->cart->subtotal >= $min_amount ) 
        return; 

    // Display an error notice for Wholesale user role
    if ( in_array( $targeted_role, $user->roles ) ) 
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __("As a Wholesale user you must have a minimal order total of %s.") , wc_price($min_amount) ), 'error' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

[image]

---

For Two user roles and two minimal amounts you will use the following:

```
// Cart and checkout validation
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'minimal_total_required' ); // Cart and Checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'minimal_total_required' ); // Checkout (optional)
function minimal_total_required() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Exit for non logged users
    if( $user->ID == 0 ) return;

    ## -- YOUR SETTINGS BELOW (For 2 user roles and 2 minimal amounts) -- ##

    $min_amount    = array( 50, 40 ); // Minimal order amounts
    $targeted_role = array('wholesale_buyer', 'customer'); // Targetted User roles

    $cart_subtotal  = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    // Wholesale user
    if ( in_array( $targeted_role[0], $user->roles ) && $cart_subtotal < $min_amount[0]){
        $text = sprintf( __('As a Wholesale user you must have a minimal order total amount of %s.'), wc_price($min_amount[0]) );
    }
    // Customer user
    elseif ( in_array( $targeted_role[1], $user->roles ) && $cart_subtotal < $min_amount[1]){
        $text = sprintf( __('You must have a minimal order total amount of %s.'), wc_price($min_amount[1]) );
    }

    // Display an error notice for Wholesale user role
    if( isset($text) )
        wc_add_notice( $text, 'error' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> It will display a different notice for each user role.

Comment: Thanks Loic!  I need to set one more user role minimum in addition to the wholesale.  If I make two pluggins like this would that work?  Or how would I add in an extra minimum amt for another userole.  Sorry, I'm not very good with code.

Comment: @Vash I have added some other code in the answer that handle 2 user roles, 2 minimal amounts and 2 different error messages.